# How to display Word Document?

Tags: excel, vba

how can display the document from this code:

```
Dim xTable As Word.Table
Dim xDoc As Word.Document
Dim xExcel As Excel.Application
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim xRow As Integer
Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set xWs = xWb.Sheets(1)
xRow = 1
Count = 0

folName = InputBox("Schreiben Sie bitte den Name des Ordners", "Ordner Name", "AZ xx.xx.xxxx")
If folName = "" Then Exit Sub

Dim strMailboxName As String: strMailboxName = "Inkasso Webpost"
Set myfolder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName).Folders("Folders").Folders(folName)
Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = myfolder
Set SubFolderEmail = Session.Folders(strMailboxName).Folders("Folders").Folders("Erledigte")


For Each maill In myfolder.Items


Set xDoc = maill.GetInspector.WordEditor 'loop through all E/Mails in folder


    For ss = 1 To xDoc.Tables.Count 'search table in the E/Mail

        If xDoc.Tables.Count = 0 Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Count = Count + 1

    Set xTable = xDoc.Tables(ss) 'download the table from E/Mail into Excel
        Range("A" & xRow).Select
        xTable.Range.Copy
        xWs.Paste
        xRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 3

        End If
    Next
Next
```

When I set my mouse on `xDoc` I see that xDoc have a name - `Dokument1`, `Dokument2`, `Dokument3` etc.

How can I  open this doc?

And when the doc gets to Number 71 I receive an error (error is, that the dokument can no longer change its name). How can I delete or close these 71 documents?

Comment: Did you try `xDoc.Close` right before your last `Next` statement? That should close the document.

Comment: this doesn't work  :\

Comment: does `Set xDoc  = Nothing` in the same place (right before your last `Next` statement) solve the issue?

Comment: no, every time xDoc increases its number ... I don't know why. I'm trying Null, Nothing, but to no avail. the only way to get 1 is to close excel and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the document to a file if you need to open it in Word. The [Document.SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.SaveAs2) method saves the specified document with a new name or format. Some of the arguments for this method correspond to the options in the `Save As` dialog box (`File` tab).

If you just need to display the changed or updated content you may use the `Display` method of the `MailItem` class. But I'd suggest saving your changes by using the `Save` method of the `MailItem` class.

To optimize the code and release all underlying COM objects instantly I'd suggest settings them to NULL (Nothing in VB):

```
Dim inspector as Outlook.Inspector = Nothing
For Each maill In myfolder.Items

Set inspector = maill.GetInspector() 
Set xDoc = inspector.WordEditor 'loop through all E/Mails in folder


    For ss = 1 To xDoc.Tables.Count 'search table in the E/Mail

        If xDoc.Tables.Count = 0 Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Count = Count + 1

    Set xTable = xDoc.Tables(ss) 'download the table from E/Mail into Excel
        Range("A" & xRow).Select
        xTable.Range.Copy
        xWs.Paste
        xRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 3

        End If
    Next

xDoc = Nothing
inspector = Nothing

Next
```

Comment: Hi Eugene Astafiev, do you know how i can "empry" the cash memory, cause after new start of the macro, the xDoc is not 1, sometimes is 10 or 18 or 16 etc, but never 0. This method with SaveAs is ok. 10x

Comment: In VBA you need to set variable or object pointers to NULL when you are done.

Comment: no, every time xDoc increases its number ... I don't know why. I'm trying Null, Nothing, but to no avail. the only way to get xDoc 1 is to close excel and reopen it.

Comment: `Dim xDoc As Word.Document` which number is increased?

Comment: `For each mail in my folder`


`Set xDoc = maill.GetInspector.WordEditor`

Here, when I set xDoc, every time xDoc changes its name until the name becomes Dokument71, sometimes when it becomes Dokument73 and the Macro stops.

Comment: Try to set them to `Nothing` as shown in the sample code.

Comment: Hi, I found out why the code doesn't work - low memory.  My VM has too little memory and that's the reason.  On a normal computer - no problem.  10x a lot for your help.